# Kafka Streams replication factor not applied to state store changelog topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

We are using Kafka Streams via Spring Cloud Stream integration. I configured the replication factor to be used across all internal Kafka Streams topics by setting

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.replication.factor=${REPL_FACTOR}
```

It works for most repartition/changelog topics used internally by Kafka Streams. However, it looks like this setting has no effect on state store changelog topics that get created manually via `Materialized#as(StoreSupplier)`. For those topics I can still see the replication factor is set to default 1. It's also not possible to set it using `Materialized#withLoggingEnabled(Map<String, String>)` because this only accepts topic-level configs (`replication.factor` is Streams config). Is this a known bug in Kafka Streams? I couldn't find anything. If so, is there a workaround to increase the replication factor for those changelog topics?

We are using Kafka v2.3.1 on the broker side and 2.5.0 on client side.

Comment: I am not too familiar with streams, but you can change the default on the broker. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#default.replication.factor Not sure if that will help.

Comment: Description says this setting is only applied for 'automatically created topics' so I guess only if [auto.create.topics.enable](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#auto.create.topics.enable) is set to true (which is not the case for us).

Comment: See my answer; I've added a note to the JIRA to fix the documentation. Also, what version are you using? I just tested it with 3.0.8 and it works as expected; see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 2.4, the `AdminClient` can now set the replication factor to -1 in `NewTopic`, meaning that the `default.replication.factor` should be used when creating topics - [KIP-464](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-464%3A+Defaults+for+AdminClient%23createTopic).

However, it appears that Kafka Streams does not currently use this feature; there is an open issuee [KAFKA-8531](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8531) for this.

You can set the replication factor for internal topics using

```
StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG)
```

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#replication.factor

> The replication factor for change log topics and repartition topics created by the stream processing application.

Since you are setting that, via the binder config, it should work as expected.

**EDIT**

What version of spring-cloud-stream are you using? I just tested with 3.0.8 and it works as expected.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.replication.factor: 3
```

> 2020-10-15 12:03:55,601 ERROR [kafka-stre] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread:673 - stream-thread [kafka-streams-inventory-processor-b8d07a5a-f3c4-476a-a265-119163d2acb7-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following unexpected Kafka exception during processing, this usually indicate Streams internal errors:
> org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Could not create topic kafka-streams-inventory-processor-inventory-counts-changelog.

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.